# quickly turn copied content (formatted text, images) to the clipboard into local markdown files and images

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, pandoc, converters

I'm looking for a very fast, hassle-free way to turn copied content (formatted text, images) to the clipboard into local markdown files and images.
That means: I just copy formatted text together with images in one go to the clipboard, e.g. from an email or from a website. Then I would want to paste this content somewhere (e.g something like OneNote, Evernote, Dropbox Papers, an IDE like VS Code...) that retains the formatting and especially also the images. That "somewhere" should offer me a straightaway possibility to export and save the pasted content to a local md file plus local images. From within Dropbox Paper and Notion.so this is possible via a simple button click ("Export to md" whatever) - yet, they have the following drawbacks: Dropbox does not export the images locally, they remain in the cloud with a link to those in the exported md file. Notion.so does the export but it cannot copy and paste text + images in one go there and the formatting handling is poor (e.g. tables are not converted and remain in the cloud).
Certainly, Pandoc does that beautifully and is my first choice but is there a way to do it even faster, maybe a browser-based solution without the need for a local installation (and without falling back on websites where to upload files). Is there a feature available in VS Code that supports text + multiple images in one go ("Paste Image" extension and others only support single images).
Any suggestion?

Comment: not sure I understand your use-case... if you want local markdown and image files.. just create them locally...?

Comment: I re-worded the whole question to better outline the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first choice meanwhile is this: https://github.com/euangoddard/clipboard2markdown.
By far the easiest solution. It nicely handles the images in particular. Kudos to the dev!